# DataList SelectedIndexChange event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have hyperlink and a hidden field inside a datalist as shown below

```
<asp:DataList ID="clientsList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="clientsList_SelectedIndexChanged1" >
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="hlName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl="#" ></asp:HyperLink>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />                     
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

When user clicks on any hyperlink, I need to store that value in an application variable. But the `SelectedIndexChange` event never fires.

This is my code:

```
protected void clientsList_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        int idx = clientsList.SelectedIndex;
        HiddenField hiddenCID = clientsList.Items[idx].FindControl("HiddenFieldID") as HiddenField;

        if (hiddenCID != null)
        {
            Logger.UpdateLog("Selected ID: " + hiddenCID.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am binding data from database to the datalist in the `Page_load` event as below and this is working fine.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       BindDataList();
    }           
}
```

Any idea why this event is never fired?

Also is my code is right as far as accessing the `hiddenfield` value is concerned?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set commandname property of hyperlink field?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Select">Select</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now in selectedindexchanged method:

```
 protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idx = DataList1.SelectedIndex;
    Label lbl = (Label)DataList1.Items[idx].FindControl("Label1");
    int id =Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Does it work?

Comment: I think you have to use linkbutton and bind Url in databound.

Comment: There is no "commandName" property\Attribute for hyperlink. SO is it that without having "CommandName" attribute we cannot access the data of the control inside datalist?